# Deploy Magento 2.2.4 : @copyright__background-color is undefined

Tags: magento2

After I deploy it has reported such an error:

```
Compilation from source: vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-l.less
variable @copyright__background-color is undefined in file /aht/www/pt/uto_sofaandbed/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend/Demo/demo/en_US/Magento_Theme/css/source/_module.less in _module.less on line 439, column 40
437|     body {
438|         .ie9 & {

Compilation from source: /aht/www/pt/uto_sofaandbed/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-m.less
variable @copyright__background-color is undefined in file pub/static/frontend/Demo/demo/en_US/Magento_Theme/css/source/_module.less in _module.less on line 263, column 36

[Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException]
Cannot read contents from file "pub/static/frontend/Demo/demo/en_US/css/styles-l.css" Warning!file_get_contents(pub/static/frontend/Demo/demo/en_US/css/styles-l.css): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your theme's _module.less file, add following and then remove var,generated and pub/static folder from root directory. Then deploy static content again.

```
@copyright__background-color: #000000;
```

Comment: I followed what you said, but it reported an error in another variable.
I have copied two style-l.css and style-m.css files from the demo to put them into public, then I successfully deployed. I do not know why it was such an error.

Answer (score 2):

had the same problem while deploying

```
    Compilation from source: /var/www/html/magento/magento_local/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-m.less
    variable @copyright__background-color is undefined in file /var/www/html/magento/magento_quick/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend/CustomTheme/custom/en_US/Magento_Theme/css/source/_module.less in _module.less on line 283, column 36
281| 
282|     .copyright {
283|         .lib-css(background-color, @copyright__background-color);
284|         .lib-css(color, @color-white);
285|         box-sizing: border-box;
286|         display: block;
```

then I solved by adding a line of code in

> app/design/frontend/CustomTheme/custom/web/css/source/_theme.less

```
@copyright__background-color: @color-gray-middle4;
```

hope it will help for you.